# Query to select most matching entry

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
left  | right
--------------
123   | test
12345 | test2
1234  | test3
```

Need to find most matching entry in left column and output the entry from right column.

Example: I want to find most matching entry for 12345678 (it is 12345 | test2) and get test2 in output. I have tried locate, but do not know how to output right column.

Comment: you need to put the column names in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by 'Mosty Mostacho' is good, which mentions you need to find the Levenshtein distance. Here's another way to do it, just get all the terms like your input string and then order the result by your `LEFT` column in descending

```
SELECT 
  `right` 
FROM 
  mytable 
WHERE 
  '12345678' LIKE CONCAT(`left`,'%') 
ORDER BY 
  `left` DESC 
LIMIT 
  1
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/842a1/4)

Comment: mysql> SELECT `right` FROM test WHERE CONCAT(`left`,'%') LIKE '12345678';
    Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @user2079197 Yes, I updated it with a SQL Fiddle example later

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
SELECT Coulmn2
FROM Table
WHERE  MATCH ( Coumn1)
AGAINST (  '%$keywords%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$  
    CREATE PROCEDURE FIND(IN @yourtext varchar(100))

       BEGIN
          DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
          myloop: LOOP

             IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM your_table 
             WHERE LeftColumn LIKE '%'+substr(@yourtext,0,length(LeftColumn)-a)+'%')
             SELECT RightColumn FROM your_table 
             WHERE LeftColumn LIKE '%'+substr(@yourtext,0,length(LeftColumn)-a)+'%'
             LEAVE myloop;
             END IF

             SET a=a-1;
             select a;
             IF a=0 THEN
                LEAVE myloop;
             END IF;
       END LOOP myloop;
    END $$
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@yourtext varchar(100))

       BEGIN
          DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
      ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You will have to clarify what `most matching entry` means. I understand you mean calculating a [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for all elements and getting the one with the least of them.

So, first you will have to create a User Defined Function to calculate the distance. Check this [link](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=552).

Once you have the UDF set up, the query you should run is:

```
select `right` from t
order by levenshtein('your_word', `left1`)
limit 1
```